# Remove elements from vector after a string match

Tags: r

I need to remove elements from a vector after a string match as below:

```r
months = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
          "jul", "ago", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")

month = "jun"

### ENTER MAGIC ###

# desired output
months
#> [1] "jan" "feb" "mar" "apr" "may" "jun"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a single match, you can do the following:

```
months <- months[1:which(months == month)]
```

**Output**

```
> months
[1] "jan" "feb" "mar" "apr" "may" "jun"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
months[1:which(months == month)]
```

or if you do not want to include the last entry

```
months[1:which(months == month)-1]
```

Comment: This only removes where there's a match, the OP wants to keep that one and remove everything *after* the match.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `cumsum`

```
months[cumsum(cumsum(months == month)) <2]
#[1] "jan" "feb" "mar" "apr" "may" "jun"
```

---

Or with `match`

```
months[seq_len(match(month, months))]
```